# instantiating a database object issue

Tags: php, autoload

I have a problem with my database class. I am pushing all the methods I need in it and after  closing the class, I am making an instance of it and affecting it to a $database variable. Then on the index page I don't require the file explicitly, because I am setting an __autoload function to do that for me. But when I just try to use $database->isConnected() method I had set for instance, it doesn't work. I have to make another instance of the $database on the index page, means recall new dataBase(); again, and only then the autoload works.

Here I don't need any code, just want someone to give me the logical reason why it does that. I'd like to understand things better than just copy paste. Because I had found a workaround, which is simply to make an instance everytime on a newpage and vere in the class page.

Comment: You *should* post code. It's hard to figure out what exactly you mean from your explanation.

Comment: yes i wasn't quite clear in my question , philip got my point and it's pretty resolved now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I got from your explanation:

**File:** database.php

```
class Database {
    isConnected() {
        //Some code
    }
}
$database = new Database();
```

**File:** index.php

```
function __autoload ($class) {
     include $class+'.php';  //Note this is highly unsafe
}
$database->isConnected();
```

---

The problem is that `__autoload()` isn't doing what you think it does.

`__autoload()` load classes that aren't already defined when they are referred to. But PHP doesn't know that `$database` is of class `Database`. As far as it's concerned, it's an undefined variable at that point.

So if you did:

**File:** database.php

```
class Database {
    isConnected() {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

**File:** index.php

```
$database = new Database();
```

PHP would realise that database isn't defined and call `__autoload()` which would load the database.php (assuming `__autoload()` is defined correctly). Then the constructor would run and `$database` would be set correctly.

What you should do is either include the database file (`include 'database.php'`) or use a static method (e.g. `Database::getDatabase();`) - the class is referred to so PHP knows to `__autoload()` it.

Comment: yes, eeffectivly ,i have used the static methodes and they worked perfectly.

Comment: thanls a lot philip, ur explanation was crystal clear for me. i hope other people would find it as useful as i've found it).

Comment: yes i am trying to like ur answer, but it says i am new.. i need 15 reputation and stuffs... but for sure ur answer was pretty clear and sooo helpful... thanks again.))